# Adding GDPR to Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, admob, program-entry-point, ads

**Why is the GDPR form not showing?**

**I put this in `build.gradle`:**

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}

implementation 'com.google.android.ads.consent:consent-library:1.0.3'
```

**And this in the main:**

```
import android.util.Log;
import com.google.ads.consent.*;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;


ConsentForm form;
private static final String TAG = "MainActivity ----- : " ;


 ConsentInformation consentInformation = ConsentInformation.getInstance(MainActivity.this);
        String[] publisherIds = {"pub-9138443983781653"};
        consentInformation.requestConsentInfoUpdate(publisherIds, new ConsentInfoUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onConsentInfoUpdated(ConsentStatus consentStatus) {
                // User's consent status successfully updated.
                Log.d(TAG,"onConsentInfoUpdated");
                switch (consentStatus){
                    case PERSONALIZED:
                        Log.d(TAG,"PERSONALIZED");
                        ConsentInformation.getInstance(MainActivity.this)
                                .setConsentStatus(ConsentStatus.PERSONALIZED);
                        break;

                    case NON_PERSONALIZED:
                        Log.d(TAG,"NON_PERSONALIZED");
                        ConsentInformation.getInstance(MainActivity.this)
                                .setConsentStatus(ConsentStatus.PERSONALIZED);
                        break;

                    case UNKNOWN:
                        Log.d(TAG,"UNKNOWN");
                        if(ConsentInformation.getInstance(MainActivity.this).isRequestLocationInEeaOrUnknown()){


                            URL privacyUrl = null;
                            try {
                                // TODO: Replace with your app's privacy policy URL.
                                privacyUrl = new URL("https://www.appprivacy.com/privacyurl");
                            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                                // Handle error.
                            }
                            form = new ConsentForm.Builder(MainActivity.this, privacyUrl)
                                    .withListener(new ConsentFormListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onConsentFormLoaded() {
                                            // Consent form loaded successfully.
                                            Log.d(TAG,"onConsentFormLoaded");
                                            showform();
                                        }

                                        @Override
                                        public void onConsentFormOpened() {
                                            // Consent form was displayed.
                                            Log.d(TAG,"onConsentFormOpened");
                                        }

                                        @Override
                                        public void onConsentFormClosed(
                                                ConsentStatus consentStatus, Boolean userPrefersAdFree) {
                                            // Consent form was closed.
                                            Log.d(TAG,"onConsentFormClosed");
                                        }

                                        @Override
                                        public void onConsentFormError(String errorDescription) {
                                            // Consent form error.
                                            Log.d(TAG,"onConsentFormError");
                                            Log.d(TAG,errorDescription);
                                        }
                                    })
                                    .withPersonalizedAdsOption()
                                    .withNonPersonalizedAdsOption()
                                    .build();

                            form.load();

                        }else{
                            Log.d(TAG,"PERSONALIZED else");
                            ConsentInformation.getInstance(MainActivity.this)
                                    .setConsentStatus(ConsentStatus.PERSONALIZED);
                        }


                        break;

                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailedToUpdateConsentInfo(String errorDescription) {
                // User's consent status failed to update.
                Log.d(TAG,"onFailedToUpdateConsentInfo");
                Log.d(TAG,errorDescription);
            }
        });




    }

    private void showform(){
        if (form!=null){
            Log.d(TAG,"show ok");
            form.show();
        }}
```

**When I debug the app I found that the app is not entered into:**

> @Override
>                   public void onConsentInfoUpdated(ConsentStatus consentStatus)

Is there something wrong in the code? And if we want to update an old app
should we add just simple code like that or change every unit?

Comment: i made video on consent sdk take look here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_JOapnq8hrs&t=768s

Answer (score 0):

Add this:

```
ConsentInformation.getInstance(MainActivity.this).setDebugGeography(DebugGeography.DEBUG_GEOGRAPHY_EEA);
```